# Constructing Dependencies from a Pillar in Saltstack

Tags: dependency-management, salt, jinja, templating

I'm trying to create a dummy state in Salt to pull dependencies from a list derived from a pillar.

In my `top.sls` file, I have:

```
base:
  '*':
    - components
```

Then, in `components.sls`, I have:

```
{% if 'components' in pillar.items() %}
include:
{% for component in pillar.get('components',[]) %}
  - {{ component }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if 'components' in pillar.items() %}
components:
  require:
{% for component in pillar.get('components',[]) %}
    - {{ component }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

When I check the pillar contents, I see:

```
$ salt my-minion-id pillar.items

my-minion-id:
    ----------
    components:
        - a-dependency-name
```

But when I try to see the set of states, I see:

```
$ salt my-minion-id state.show_sls components

my-minion-id:
    ----------
```

...and that's it.

My ultimate goal, here, is to treat the minion as hostile, so I'm trying to pull role details out of pillars instead of assigning roles in my `file_root`'s `top.sls`. It's my understanding that every minion has full access to the contents of the file_root, and I don't want a hostile minion to know the specific firewall or services of any unrelated node.

**Edit:**

I discovered that my pillar structure didn't support pillar merging, as it used lists, so I switched to a pillar-structure that used no-value dicts:

```
my-minion-id:
    ----------
    components:
        ----------
        a-dependency-name:
            None
```

Comment: Pretty advanced question on salt stack, genuine question from a Chef user: I had understood salt as a push model, how could a node (minion ?) register itself ? (That's just out of curiosity)

Comment: Ask that as a separate question, and I'll see if I can put together a satisfactory answer without bouncing against my NDA.

Comment: Fair enough, but my last inspection of salt stack didn't meet my requirements (specially on windows boxes) so I'll see if I can make something unbiased and if I really have time to. Tried as comment just in case I missed something obvious :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep for chat yet, so this will have to do. But in brief: A salt minion running on a node will use DNS to find out where its salt master is, and will reach out  to the master. Master will dump the minion's key into a pending queue until someone accepts it.

Comment: (And wouldn't "unbiased" questions be more a wiki thing? Dunno.)

Comment: As far as I know association bonus works for chat, you have far over 20, so this should work for [chat] :) Thanks for the pointer minions can  ask to be registered themselves, I had missed this approach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57307/discussion-between-michael-mol-and-tensibai).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This templated SLS file works splendidly:

```
{% if 'components' in salt.pillar.items() %}

include:
{% for component in salt.pillar.get('components').keys() %}
  - {{ component }}
{% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

However, it requires changing my pillar key structure. From the original question, you see the structure as:

```
my-minion-id:
    ----------
    components:
        - a-dependency-name
```

Instead, it needs to be:

```
my-minion-id:
    ----------
    components:
        ----------
        a-dependency-name:
            None
```

Note that `a-dependency-name` is now a dict, and has a single key/value, `None`. Thus the pillar SLS file needs to change from

```
components:
  - a-dependency-name
```

to

```
components:
  a-dependency-name: ~
```

While you can get away with not using no-value dictionaries (and thus get rid of the `.keys()` in the template) and use lists instead, if you do that, you can't merge the `components` from multiple different pillars; each pillar Salt applies will override the `components` key from the previous, and the last pillar read will win. If you want to merge pillars (we *are* talking about role-based assignment, here), this would appear to be the necessary construct.

With that, the output of `salt my-minion-id state.show_sls components` is then correct:

```
$ salt my-minion-id state.show_sls components
my-minion-id:
    ----------
    a-dependency-name:
      ----------
      ...
```

`pillar.items()` in Jinja templates turns out not to be *quite* equivalent to `salt.pillar.items()`; if you try using `pillar.ls()`, for example, you may see the following error:

```
Rendering SLS 'base:components' failed: Jinja variable 'salt.pillar object' has no attribute 'ls'
```

Whether that means one should avoid the implicit `salt.` prefix shortcut Jinja provides, or instead use a construct like `{% if pillar['components'] is defined %}` (thanks, @brousch, for the advice), I can't say.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do it like:

```
{% if pillar['components'] is defined %}
include:
{% for component in pillar['components'] %}
 - {{ component }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}

{% if pillar['components'] is defined %}
components:
  require:
{% for component in pillar['components'] %}
 - {{ component }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```